# Spring Boot + File Upload Does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have recently started Spring Boot in my application.
There is a file upload utility that used to work fine when using tomcat8 but after switching to Spring boot its not working.

Below is the code.

JSP

```
<form id="fileupload" action="/myApp/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table id="files" style="border-spacing:0px 5px;margin-top:5px;">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td><input type="file" class="btn btn-info" name="files" id="files0"></td>
    </tr></tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public String upload(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile files, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders httpHeaders, Model model, Locale locale) {
        LOGGER.debug("Entering upload");
    }
```

Spring Boot Config :

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, MultipartAutoConfiguration.class })
@Configuration  
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource(value = "classpath:/context.xml")
public class MyApplication {

public MyApplication() {
    super();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

my Mvc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="messageSource"     class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages/messages"/>
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.my">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
</context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager">
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true" >
        <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>

<mvc:resources location="/css/**" mapping="/css/" />
<mvc:resources location="/js/**" mapping="/js/" />
<mvc:resources location="/img/**" mapping="/img/" />
<mvc:resources location="/fonts/**" mapping="/fonts/" />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.lang.Exception">error</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="0"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="contentNegotiationManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
</bean>
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="-1" />    
</bean>

<bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="prefixJson" value="false" />
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
    <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/> 
</bean>
```

Exception stacktrace :

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required MultipartFile parameter 'files' is not present
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:251)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:94)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1526)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1482)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I have tried @SpringBootApplication on my boot application class, but that didnt help. I am using embedded tomcat.

I have searched various blogs and SO questions but was not able to resolve it.
Please help.

Comment: Are you running an embedded tomcat or still deploying?

Answer (score -3):

Spring Boot and File Upload works fine. The documentation is available [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration). With the default configuration, it multi-part file upload works out of the box.

From the code you have posted, I don't think you have configured Spring Boot correctly. Start [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/). For example, I see that you don't have the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation in `MyApplication` which triggers Spring Boot to implement the standard configuration.

Comment: He has `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@ComponentScan` and `@Configuration` for which `@SpringBootApplication` is nothing more then a shorter version.

Comment: Right... which leads me to question whether he configured Spring Boot correctly. It is a common problem solving strategy to start with the  known good configuration - only `@SpringBootApplication` - confirming functionality, and then adding variables.

Comment: Adding `@SpringBootApplication` doesn't change a thing, it is only a shorthand for the 3 annotations. It will change nothing.

Comment: No, my suggestion is to *remove* all of the other annotations and *start* with `@SpringBootApplication` as specified in the link that I provided to the Spring Boot tutorial. This puts you at a known good state from which you can confirm that file upload at least works, and then start changing configuration *as necessary*. This is how you are supposed to work with Spring Boot anyways. Start with the basic configuration until the basic configuration does not fit, at which point you start tweaking the configuration.

Comment: Which again changes nothing as [`@SpringBootApplication`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) is nothing more then the 3 annotations he already has... Also what you state about Spring Boot is true for a NEW application he is porting an application which is a whole different beast...

Comment: I'm not interested in the 3 annotations covered by `@SpringBootApplication`. I am interested in removing things like `@ImportResource`. Start from the basics. I have done many ports, and I have followed the same approach. Eliminate variables, start from well known state. Start adding things back once the fundamentals have been proven. This is a basic debugging technique.

Comment: Not when porting apps imho. The working state is the application as you had it, you go back to that and then remove things that Spring Boot gives you. But doing that is a whole different discussion. The point is it doesn't add anything nor removes anything.

Comment: I disagree. I have done exactly this when debugging issues that arise porting applications. Because in almost all cases, it has been a configuration problem. Thus, I want to know what is going on in isolation before adding customization.  An ordinary Spring Framework application and a Spring Boot application are configured very differently, and this difference is causing the problem. Start with the simplest possible test case - which is exactly as the tutorial says. If you can get form upload to work in a controlled situation, then you are adding customization on a solid foundation.